# Visual Novel Decision Structure in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, unity-game-engine, structure

I have been trying to figure this out for some time now. Multiple searches have turned up little so I am hoping for help. I have a pretty good grasp of C#, but I am not too experienced with structure or how to go about things the best way. I am currently working on my first indie game with a group as their lead programmer since I am almost graduated with a degree in game programming, and making good progress. We are making a visual novel in Unity (I mostly want to use if for art/sound assets and handling scenes for me) and I am about as far as I can get with the code before I need to start implementing the decision structure for the player.

Now most of the tutorials or guides I have found say a simple switch or if/then statement will work. The problem is that in a longer game with multiple timelines I am not sure how efficient this will be. For example, some of the decisions might not be hit, or hit at different times. This poses a problem for lines of dialogue that take more then one decision to reach. If the player chooses to go left, and open a door vs go right and kick over a bucket would I have to have 4 separate variables for it?

This is tough to explain as I am not quite sure how these decision structures are typically setup, and everything I read either shows a simple statement for 1 question and a resulting scene, or just says to use a visual novel engine. I hope to expand to a point and click game sometime down the road. 
So my main question is, how would I go about structuring a decision tree in terms of storage and processing? My best guess so far was to store a struct or list of objects, and each object is a decision that stores previous requirements within it. This also means that in order to choose dialog the program would skip down the tree from the very first connection (object linked to object).

Could I setup a way of storing specific choices somehow? The more complex the tree gets the harder it will be. If you get down a path that takes you down 100+  decisions for example it would make the dialog options longer and longer. What am I missing here?

I figure I can store each decision containing an enumerator for A, B, C, or D. Left or right kind of questions would only use A and B so to speak. But if you have a dialog option that takes an enumerator it would end up looking like this.

Kyle:choiceHallway:1:choiceDoor2:"Welcome to the left hallway's door!";

I suppose the door cannot be reached unless you go down the first hallway anyway, but I feel like that could pose problems down the road when you make assumptions that something cannot be reached unless you do this, and makes for bugs in selection choices because of it. Is there a better way of going about this?

I should note I am using a mysql database to store dialog right now. I already have the import/export working, just not the processing for it.

Comment: This question would be greatly improved with paragraphs. (Ironic, given the topic.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a gamedevelopment perspective, I want to easily manipulate the variables/ conditions requirements for e.g. a quest, or level etc.

I'd suggest going for a collection of requirements consisting of scriptable objects. You can store them in objects that you can easily manipulate from within the inspector.

You could create a decision named "Kick the bucket".

```
[CreateAssetMenuAttribute(menuName = "Decision")]
public Decision : ScriptableObject
{
   public string Name;
   public DecisionState State; // Use an Enum with states "Inactive" "Completed", "Failed", "Unavailable" etc.
   // Other variables that may be relevant, like score or whatever   
}
```

You would set the State to it's default state upon gamestart. Then when you select to kick the bucket, flag it to whatever state you desire.

You can then make requirements, accepting a decision and a desired state.

```
[CreateAssetMenuAttribute(menuName = "Requirement")]
public Requirement : ScriptableObject
{
   public Decision Decision;
   public DecisionState State;
}
```

Now in your room, chapter or whatever script, you can attach a list of requirements needed to do whatever logic you desire. You could run the CheckRequirements method to see if all requirments are met.

```
public Room : MonoBehaviour
{
   public List<Requirement> Requirements;

   public bool CheckRequirements()
   {
      foreach (var requirement in Requirements)
      {
         if (requirement.Decision.State != requirement.State)
         {
            return false;
         }
      }
      return true;
   }
}
```

The reason why i love this approach is that you can easily create new decisions and requirements and afterwards drag and drop them into the inspector slots. So when you have a change in gameflow, you can simply add or remove a decision/ requirement.

**Edit:**

Had some time and did some thinking...

To make it even more design friendly, you could also integrate UnityEvents that fire upon entering a room and setting certain decisions for you.

```
public Room : MonoBehaviour
{
   UnityEvent OnRoomEnter;

   public void OnEnable() // Or whatever function you call when instantiating a room
   {
      OnRoomEnter();
   }

}
```

Then consider the following

```
public GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
   public void SetDecisionToActive(Decision decision)
   {
      decision.State = DecisionState.Active;
   }

    public void SetDecisionToInactive(Decision decision)
   {
      decision.State = DecisionState.Inactive;
   }
   // etc...
}
```

You can now drag and drop your gamemanager into the events slot of a 'room' monobehaviour object in Unity, select a method, then drag one of your created decisions into it's parameter slot.

Comment: This sounds absolutely perfect, one last thing though. Would I store the requirements for the dialog into my DB then? I suppose I could add an extra column for that, but would there be a more efficient way? This stores the decisions for easy checking, but how would I go about setting up what I check them against?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to store the requirements in your database. It seems to me that this logic is better off in the application. 
Or is there a use-case where it is beneficial for you to have it in the database?

Comment: I think I explained it poorly. A bit of info to help. I have my 'game' database with each scene as a 'table.' at the beginning of every scene i load all the text, which is stored with the character name, character image, maybe a sound effect to go with it, that sort of thing. I load them into my dialougmanager and my scenemanager requests them. So how should I determine the choices that are made? Would I store every single line table and number that it determines within the decision object and run a check every line? or would i store the check elsewhere such as within another object.

Comment: Essentially I don't know how each line will be 'defined' so that it links to its respective decision if the decision is kept separate as its own object. If i store the line numbers within each object I can have my scenemanager check at the beginning of every scene which decisions will come into play and line up the text accordingly, or I could store the decision name into the db as a string and the dialougmanager just has to call it when it realizes there is a pre-requisite. Or I could have a decisionstructure object that stores all the decisions and manages which lines go with which choices.

Comment: I'm finding it hard to visualize your database - code structure. 
To me it would seem logical to minimize database calls and data to retrieve 
So if you could get away with just calling/ checking for an Id or Name of a decision, i'd say go for that. 
Ultimately it depends on the entire picture. I often start with writing it all out in a diagram, which helps in identifying potential bottlenecks. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for a [finite state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). I wouldn't attempt to represent the entire game in a single state machine, but break things down (e.g. into "chapters" or similar) that would each have their own state machine, and the collection of "chapters" would be a state machine itself (e.g. you can only transition to chapter 4 if you've already completed chapters 2 and 3, but you can transition to either chapter 2 or 3 after completing chapter 1, etc.).

This is one I've worked with in "normal" C# projects (i.e. not Unity), but it *should* work with Unity, and it's pretty simple to get set up: https://github.com/MassTransit/Automatonymous. Also, look into "sagas" in the docs. While not directly applicable, they will give you some direction in orchestrating multiple state machines.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little answer.Hope this will help you .As i understand you need an abstract solution not if else in every statement .Make graph of objects like (https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVpih.jpg)  ,make path and set like isInRoomVariable =true and you object which will show you from where you came even functions what can you do when you are in left room or in right room